# GET milliseconds with DATE_FORMAT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to return a date with a certain format, for the moment I'm using:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(3),'%y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')
```

which returns:

```
18-02-26 11:22:07.617000
```

that's perfect for now, however, I want to get Milleseconds, which means only 3 characters after the seconds, something like: `18-02-26 11:22:07.617` and I'm obliged to do it with `DATE_FORMAT`.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can use MICROSECOND()  in any format   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_microsecond

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want use `DATE_FORMAT` you can do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(3), '%d-%b-%y %H:%m:%s.%f'),1,22);
```

Comment: format :'%d-%b-%y %H:%m:%s.%f'
%m - will return month, rather than %m but %i OR by short format: '%d-%b-%y %T.%f'

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to comment on Leo R's answer. There is a typo at the second "%m".

The correct format would be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(3), '%d-%b-%y %H:%i:%s.%f'),1,22);
```